# spring and hibernate

Tags: spring-mvc

I am beginner with spring, I have a search form and I want to error or the form is blank it sends me to the error page otherwise it sends me to the page result.

if anyone can help me
thank you

here is my code.

```
    @SuppressWarnings( { "unchecked" })
@RequestMapping("/search.html")
public String findAllData(Map model, SearchForm seachForm) {
    model.put("allData", searchService.searchData(seachForm));

    if("seachForm"!=null)
    {
            return "displayForm";
    }
    else
    {


            return "redirect:/searchForm.htm";

    }
```

Comment: Please be more specific with your question, I don't understand your problem enough to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
if("seachForm"!=null){
        return "displayForm";
}else{
        return "redirect:/searchForm.htm";
}
```

seachForm is not a String, try with

```
if(seachForm != null){
        return "displayForm";
}else{
        return "redirect:/searchForm.htm";
}
```

Greetings.

Comment: thank you for your answer
I executed the code without typing anything in the form, but it does not send me to the form page! he displays an error (tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

As MG_Bautista showed `searchForm` is definitely not a String (you should have gotten a compile error), but `searchForm` would also never be `null`. It'll just be a bunch of zero-length Strings. You have to do iterate over all fields of `searchForm` like

```
if ("".equals(searchForm.getUserName()) && 
    "".equals(searchForm.getAddress())) {
        return "displayForm";
} else {
        return "redirect:/searchForm.htm";
}
```